# Installing Windows 7 without a SuperDrive in Boot Camp on 2010 MBP

Tags: windows, bootcamp, ssd

Just switched out my SuperDrive for an SSD on my 2010 MacBook Pro and am running into whale of a time trying to get Windows 7 installed onto the SSD for Boot Camp. Initially tried installing via an external DVD drive connected over USB, but that wouldn't let me boot into Windows 7 setup. Tried setting up a Windows 7 USB stick, and that wouldn't boot either.

I then tried following along [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/m9c4c/mac_optibay_ssd_boot_camp_and_windows/) with the basic procedure of tricking VirtualBox into installing Windows 7 to your drive and going from there, but that created a non-bootable Windows partition.

There must be some way to get Windows 7 up and running WITHOUT having to reinstall the SuperDrive. Anyone have any success doing this?

BTW, I'm running 10.7.2, which means rEFIt is out, as it isn't Lion compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I was able to was by reinstalling the super drive I spent more time looking for a work around then the time it took to move the ssd to the hard drive location and reinstalling the super drive.

Sorry.

Comment: +1 just did this shuffle to get my setup (SSD Lion boot drive + Magnetic drive with Bootcamp and OSX partitions) completed. rEFIt doesn't seem to have been updated in ages. Kind of a PITA, but after a couple of swaps, the procedure is pretty quick. Looking forward to MBPs that can boot Windows from USB - maybe the rumored WWDC 2012 refresh will provide.

Answer (score 1):

So, I just broke down and installed rEFIt. It actually worked - I could boot off of the Windows USB key and install. After installation, I immediately removed rEFIt, and everything seems to be working correctly after that. I doubt this is a 100% will work in every case procedure, but so far things seem to be back to normal.